# TypeScript & React - one onChange Handler for multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Say I have a form with multiple input fields. In normal ES6/React I would create a single method that all input fields would point their `onChange` handlers to. Something like this:

```
handleChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
}
```

This helps in the case where you have a lot of form elements and don't have to create a specific method to handle each of them.

Is this possible in TypeScript? Even if it is not type-safe?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? Are you getting any errors? what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Anything you can do in JavaScript, you can do in TypeScript.

Comment: @NitzanTomer @vutran: It would result in error `TS2345`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As answered in the comments, everything you can do in JavaScript is also valid TypeScript.

However, I guess you're getting errors from the TypeScript compiler (depending on the compiler options you've set).

Assuming your component looks something like this:

```
interface ComponentProps { }
interface ComponentState {
  name: string
  address: string
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<ComponentProps, ComponentState> {
  handleChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> == External: (30,19): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ [x: number]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentState'.
>
> == External:   Property 'name' is missing in type '{ [x: number]: any; }'.

And when using the `noImplicitAny` compiler option (which I like to use), this additional error:

> == External: (28,16): error TS7006: Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.

If you're sure that your code is correct, you can silence these errors by explicitly casting the parameter for `handleChange` and the argument for `setState`

```
  handleChange(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value } as ComponentState)
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

I solved this problem like this:

```
handleChange = (field: string) => (event) => {
    this.setState({ [field]: event.target.value } as Pick<State, any>);
};

...

<Input onChange={this.handleChange('myField')} />
```

The Accepted answer didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Form = () => {
  const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState<{ [x: string]: string }>()

  const handleFormSubmit = async (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const data = {
      name: inputValues?.name,
      email: inputValues?.email,
      phone: inputValues?.phone,
      income: inputValues?.name
    }

    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };

    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://xyz/form-submit', requestOptions)
      const res = await response.json()
      console.log(res)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  const handleInputChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.currentTarget
    setInputValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }))
  }

  return (
    <div className="Form">
      <div className="form-wrapper">
        <h1>Demo Form for React</h1>
        <form className="form">
          <input 
            className="form-input"
            name="name" 
            value={inputValues?.name || ''} 
            onChange={handleInputChange} 
            placeholder="Your Name"
            type="text"
            data-testid="form-input-name"
          />
          <input 
            className="form-input"
            name="phone" 
            value={inputValues?.phone || ''} 
            onChange={handleInputChange} 
            placeholder="Your Phone" 
            type="tel"
            data-testid="form-input-phone"
          />
          <input 
            className="form-input" 
            name="email"
            value={inputValues?.email || ''} 
            onChange={handleInputChange} 
            placeholder="Your Email" 
            type="email"
            data-testid="form-input-email"
          />
          <input 
            className="form-input"
            name="income"
            value={inputValues?.income || ''} 
            onChange={handleInputChange} 
            placeholder="Your Annual Income" 
            type="number"
            data-testid="form-input-income"
          />
          <button 
            className='form-submit'
            data-testid="form-submit" 
            onClick={handleFormSubmit}
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

A sample **Typescript** form. It's features:

- A single `onChange` handler
- One state object into which we can add as many key value pairs
  without the typescript compiler yelling at us.
- Uses ES2020 optional chaining.
- Has data-testid on the DOM elements incase you want to run a few unit test.
- Should provide autocomplete for the input fields as per their types.
- A form Submit function sample that uses the fetch api to make a post call to an end point.

Also, with this approach, you don't have to use `@ts-ignore`, `any` or make changes to your `tsconfig`.

**Please use it as your hearts desire.**

Comment: Thank you, this is a much better answer than the top answer in my opinion!

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the interface you have to shape that value of your state which is [e.target.name] and e.target.value type string or any as per your code.

```
interface formState {
  //it can be  (name: string address: string)
  [key: string]: string;
}

handleChange(e: any) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }
```

For example

```
interface LoginFormState {
      //can be
      //email: string
      //password: string
      [key: string]: string;
    }
    interface Props {}

    class LoginForm extends React.Component<Props, LoginFormState> {
      constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          email: "",
          password: ""
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }
      handleChange(e: any) {
        this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
        // console.log("email", this.state.email);
      }
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach is pretty simple to understand as well:

```js
interface FormData {
    firstName?: string,
    lastName?: string,
}


const [form, setForm] = useState<FormData | null>(null);
```

And the JSX

```
<input onChange={(e) => setForm({...form, firstName: e.target.value})}  />
<input onChange={(e) => setForm({...form, lastName: e.target.value})}  />
```